# IE 8/jQuery UI Dialog not initializing EXCEPT when called on localhost

Tags: jquery, security, user-interface, internet-explorer-8

I have a couple of pages with a rather simple design. A div contains an iframe or some basic form elements (a textbox and a select with a button). When I'm working on this via http://localhost/myapp everything works perfectly IE 8, FF, Chrome - it all works. However, when I switch to my machine name OR FQDN of the server it stops initializing the dialog in IE 8 only. I can see a quick error icon popup in the window, but it goes away before I can try and debug it. The code is in a try/catch and no errors are thrown there. I've tried making sure the machine name/fqdn is "trusted" or "intranet" but no difference. Again - works PERFECT on FF/Chrome when called by anything - just not IE 8. Thoughts?

Comment: You will be able to see the error that comes up by pressing F12 in IE for the developer console

Answer (score 0):

Apparently - the extra comma on the last parameter of the dialog init causes this error. Next time, I'll slow down and use JSLint.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in IE 11: the site worked when addressed as localhost, but not by machine name. In the developer console I noticed a message that intranet sites are running in compatibility mode. Apparently that is a default setting for IE.

Turned the setting off (Tools -> Compatibility View Settings -> Display intranet sites in Compatibility View -> uncheck) and the initialization went through fine.